# css pseudo class colour attribute is not working

Tags: html, css

this is HTMl and css code i used to run a sample project and im unable to understand why my css styling is different from the online compiler and the IDE(virtual studio code) so please help me in this

```css
li:first-child {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>the Basic Language of the Web: HTML</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header class="main-header">
      <h1> The Code Magazine</h1>

      <nav>
        <a href="./blog.html">Blog</a>
        <a href="#">Challenges</a>
        <a href="#">Flexbox</a>
        <a href="#">CSS Grid</a>
      </nav>
      <p>test text</p>
    </header>


      
      
  

      <h3>Why should you learn HTML?</h3>
      <p>
        There are countless reasons for learning the fundamental language of the
        web. Here are 5 of them:
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p>To be able to use the fundamental web dev language</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          To hand-craft beautiful websites instead of relying on tools like
          Worpress or Wix
        </li>
        <li>To build web applications</li>
        <li>To impress friends To have fun </li>
      </ul>
      <p>Hopefully you learned something new here. See you next time!</p>
    </article>

    <aside>
      <h4>Related posts</h4>
      <ul class="related">
        <li>
          <img
            src="img/related-1.jpg"
            alt="related 1 image"
            width="75"
            ,height="75"
          /><a href="#"> How to Learn Web Bevelopment </a>
          <p class="related-author">By Jonas Schmedtmann</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="img/related-2.jpg"
            alt="related-2 image"
            width="75"
            height="75"
          />
          <a href="#"> The Unknown Powers of CSS </a>
          <p class="related-author">By Jim Dillon</p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="img/related-3.jpg"
            alt="related-3 image"
            height="75"
            ,width="75"
          />
          <a href="#">Why JavaScript is Awesome</a>
          <p class="related-author">By Matilda</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </aside>


        </li>
        <li>
          <img
            src="img/related-3.jpg"
            alt="related-3 image"
            height="75"
            ,width="75"
          />
          <a href="#">Why JavaScript is Awesome</a>
          <p class="related-author">By Matilda</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Here I used a pseudo class to change the attribute of the first child of the `li` tag. In `.related`, the color changes in the online compiler but  when I run in VSCode the color attribute is not changing but font weight and font style attributes are changing.

thanks for helping me

[here is my screenshot run in VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNwPZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The color is changing to blue without any issues. However that is a link that you're styling. Once it's clicked, its color changes to purple.

To force the purple to be blue, or any other color, you also need to style the link using another psuedo class.

```css
li a:visited {
  color: blue;
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you have given the class `.related-author` a color it will override your `li:first-child` style since it has a higher specificity level.

Look here for eg:

```css
.related-author {
  color: grey;
}

li:first-child {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>the Basic Language of the Web: HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="main-header">
    <h1> The Code Magazine</h1>
    <nav>
      <a href="./blog.html">Blog</a>
      <a href="#">Challenges</a>
      <a href="#">Flexbox</a>
      <a href="#">CSS Grid</a>
    </nav>
    <p>test text</p>
  </header>
  <h3>Why should you learn HTML?</h3>
  <p>
    There are countless reasons for learning the fundamental language of the web. Here are 5 of them:
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>To be able to use the fundamental web dev language</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      To hand-craft beautiful websites instead of relying on tools like Worpress or Wix
    </li>
    <li>To build web applications</li>
    <li>To impress friends To have fun </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Hopefully you learned something new here. See you next time!</p>
  </article>
  <aside>
    <h4>Related posts</h4>
    <ul class="related">
      <li>
        <img src="img/related-1.jpg" alt="related 1 image" width="75" ,height="75" /><a href="#"> How to Learn Web Bevelopment </a>
        <p class="related-author">By Jonas Schmedtmann</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/related-2.jpg" alt="related-2 image" width="75" height="75" />
        <a href="#"> The Unknown Powers of CSS </a>
        <p class="related-author">By Jim Dillon</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/related-3.jpg" alt="related-3 image" height="75" ,width="75" />
        <a href="#">Why JavaScript is Awesome</a>
        <p class="related-author">By Matilda</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </aside>


  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="img/related-3.jpg" alt="related-3 image" height="75" ,width="75" />
    <a href="#">Why JavaScript is Awesome</a>
    <p class="related-author">By Matilda</p>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

To solve this, use :

```css
.related-author {
  color: grey;
}

li:first-child > * {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>the Basic Language of the Web: HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="main-header">
    <h1> The Code Magazine</h1>
    <nav>
      <a href="./blog.html">Blog</a>
      <a href="#">Challenges</a>
      <a href="#">Flexbox</a>
      <a href="#">CSS Grid</a>
    </nav>
    <p>test text</p>
  </header>
  <h3>Why should you learn HTML?</h3>
  <p>
    There are countless reasons for learning the fundamental language of the web. Here are 5 of them:
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p>To be able to use the fundamental web dev language</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      To hand-craft beautiful websites instead of relying on tools like Worpress or Wix
    </li>
    <li>To build web applications</li>
    <li>To impress friends To have fun </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Hopefully you learned something new here. See you next time!</p>
  </article>
  <aside>
    <h4>Related posts</h4>
    <ul class="related">
      <li>
        <img src="img/related-1.jpg" alt="related 1 image" width="75" ,height="75" /><a href="#"> How to Learn Web Bevelopment </a>
        <p class="related-author">By Jonas Schmedtmann</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/related-2.jpg" alt="related-2 image" width="75" height="75" />
        <a href="#"> The Unknown Powers of CSS </a>
        <p class="related-author">By Jim Dillon</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="img/related-3.jpg" alt="related-3 image" height="75" ,width="75" />
        <a href="#">Why JavaScript is Awesome</a>
        <p class="related-author">By Matilda</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </aside>


  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="img/related-3.jpg" alt="related-3 image" height="75" ,width="75" />
    <a href="#">Why JavaScript is Awesome</a>
    <p class="related-author">By Matilda</p>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: But what about the text below that link "By Jonas Schmedtmann", the text font styles and weight is changing but not colour attribute. @Omar Siddiqui